# How to retrieve the default site template in my xml module?

Tags: form-fields-types, custom-module, xml

I wish to add a formsource to a subform in my custom maded module.
The example code:

```
<field type="subform" formsource= "templates/DEFAULT_TEMPLATE/MY_MODULE/SUBFORM_NAME.xml" >
```

Comment: why don't you put your subform.xml inside your module?

Comment: Because I need to load it in template override, in cases like overrides of this module

Answer (score 1):

Create a field type based on subform. Change `formsource` handling in `__set` method.

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('subform');

class JFormFieldMysubform extends JFormFieldSubform
{
    protected $type = 'Mysubform';

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        switch ($name)
        {
            case 'formsource':
                $this->formsource = JPATH_SITE . '/templates/' . $this->getDefaultTemplate() . '/html/mod_mymodule/mysubform.xml';
                break;
            default:
                parent::__set($name, $value);
        }
    }

    private function getDefaultTemplate()
    {
        // Avoid duplicate queries
        static $template;

        if ($template === null)
        {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select($db->quoteName('template'))
                ->from($db->quoteName('#__template_styles'))
                ->where($db->quoteName('client_id') . ' = 0')
                ->where($db->quoteName('home') . ' = 1');
            $template = $db->setQuery($query)->loadResult();
        }

        return $template;
    }
}
```

Above is just a basic example. You need to add checks to ensure that the form exists. Otherwise you'll get an error:

```
Joomla\CMS\Form\Form::getInstance() could not load file
```